# Running bash script as cron job does'nt do anything

Tags: shell, scripting, cron

I have a Bash script at `/home/pi/dev/app/script.sh`

Which starts a node app to write "hello world" to a file.
Manually starting the script using works fine.
node app:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let test = 'cron working';
fs.writeFile('temp.txt', test, (err) => {

    if (err) throw err;


    console.log('saved!');
});
```

Bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
node /home/pi/dev/app/index.js
```

But:

running `crontab -e`

adding line:  `1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/pi/dev/app/script.sh`

Doesnt do anything. watching `tail -f /var/log/syslog` shows that the cron itself is being executed but it doesn't write into the file.

I tried `sudo nano /etc/crontab` adding
`1 * * * * root /bin/bash /home/pi/dev/app/script.sh`
But this also doesnt work.

I am using a RPI4 running debian.

Comment: I suggest you to quickly edit your question to add the script part that write to the file. Because it's very probably a working directory issue.

Comment: done. But as said, this manually works fine using ./script.sh

Comment: It works in both case, simply the temp.txt file is created somewhere else with crond. When you check manually, the temp.txt is simply created in the directory where you are.

Comment: i know, but the file temp.txt in this directory is not being written. It just wont work.

Comment: To be sure, add a path to the node entry `fs.writeFile('temp.txt', test`, like `fs.writeFile('/tmp/temp.txt', test`  and give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230185/discussion-between-zilog80-and-lightyears99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bash script line that launchs node is simply "node index.js", it's probably a missing PATH entry for the crond user environment. If crond is running as root, check the default environment for the root superuser, its PATH entry has to include the node.js path. You may have also to restart the running crond or `kill -SIGHUP <crond pid>` to refresh its environment settings.

For security clearance, take care that the node.js path is only writable for the root superuser. If it can't be done, it would be then more safe to use the full node.js path in your bash script without adding node.js path entry to root's PATH instead.

Comment: check for runs in /var/log/cron - or wherever your platform writes it.